# Facing issue with configure method in .Net core application

Tags: swagger, asp.net-core-webapi

I have developed .Net core API project and deployed on the server.
I added it as site on IIS(remote windows server)and tried to browse the application.

The application is not working properly facing issue at Configure method
[image]

Here is my configure method in >net core

```
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            var appName = "";
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseHsts();

            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseMvc();

            app.UseSwagger();

            // Enable middleware to serve swagger-ui (HTML, JS, CSS, etc.),
            // specifying the Swagger JSON endpoint.
            app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
            {
                c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "Api V1");
            });
}
```

Please let me know how can to add swagger endpoint.

Comment: try adding c.RoutePrefix = string.Empty; I think the /api/swagger is not something you'd expect. right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you directly publish your web application to a nested site in the default website on IIS.

So the `"/swagger/v1/swagger.json"` root path  will become `localhost/swagger/v1/swagger.json`  not `localhost/yourwebsitename/swagger/v1/swagger.json`.

To solve this issue, I suggest you could try to modify the SwaggerEndpoint path as this `c.SwaggerEndpoint("../swagger/v1/swagger.json", "Api V1");.

More details, you could refer to below startup.cs

```
        app.UseSwagger();

        // Enable middleware to serve swagger-ui (HTML, JS, CSS, etc.),
        // specifying the Swagger JSON endpoint.
        app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
        {
            c.SwaggerEndpoint("../swagger/v1/swagger.json", "Api V1");
        });
```

`